# Unable to call a step definition within another step with a dynamic object

Tags: c#, specflow

I am using specflow to write some UI tests.

**The Scenario**

```
Scenario: I can add multiple users
    Given I add the following users
        | FirstName | Surname | Age |
        | Tom       | Jerrum  | 21  |
        | Another   | Person  | 38  |
        | Jimmy     | Jones   | 25  |
    Then I have 3 users displayed
```

**The Step Definitions**

```
[Given(@"I add the following users")]
public void GivenIAddTheFollowingUsers(IEnumerable<dynamic> people)
{
    foreach(var person in people)
    {
        When(@"I go to the add person page");
        Then(@"I enter the details of the person", person);
        When(@"I save the new person");
        Then(@"I am taken back to the view people page");
    }
}


[Then(@"I enter the details of the person")]
public void ThenIEnterTheDetailsOfThePerson(dynamic person)
{
    AddPersonPage.EnterDetails(person);
}
```

When trying to execute this I get the following error...

> {"The best overloaded method match for 'TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps.When(string, TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)' has some invalid arguments"}

This error occurs when trying to call `Then(@"I enter the details of the person", person);`
The code within the step definition isn't being reached due to this error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `object` is a reserved keyword, use `obj` name instead.

Comment: Could you add the entire call stack, with the `Given` method ?

Comment: Not in this case because other steps need to be called before "step two". I will update this in the question to make it clearer.

So for each of the obj's, all three of those steps would need to be called.

Comment: I don't see any connection between the error involved and your error. You must specify us with more background code that will make that connection visible.

Comment: Where is the code for `Given` method and `TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps.When(string, TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)`?

Comment: What is in your IEnumerable<dynamic>? And hire is it getting populated? By default specflow will only bind to simple types and tables...

Comment: I work with Tom, we are using the specflow dynamic assist library. It basically reduces the need to use StepArgumentTransformations all the time. https://github.com/marcusoftnet/SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic in the case here people will contain three dynamic objects with the properties in the feature table, firstname, surname and age.

Comment: Can you show the method definition for the `When` method that is being called? It seems like you have a method which looks like `[When("some text")]public void WhenSomeText(string someValue, Table table)` based on your error and then you are calling it with a dynamic object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this is to build up a table for each person...

```
[Given(@"I add the following users")]
public void GivenIAddTheFollowingUsers(IEnumerable<dynamic> people)
{
    foreach(var person in people)
    {
        var header = new [] {"FirstName", "Surname", "Age"};
        var personTable = new Table(header);
        personTable.AddRow(person.FirstName, person.Surname, person.Age);

        When(@"I go to the add person page");
        Then(@"I enter the details of the person", personTable);
        When(@"I save the new person");
        Then(@"I am taken back to the view people page");
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but I want to avoid having to build up a new table for each person.